# SAPUI5 - How to bind the correct property of a sublist in a table?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Guys I'm with a problem.

I've a page with a form and all data is binding ok. But not the table.

My object is:

```
this.getView().getModel('newExpense').setData({
  desiredPaymentDate: new Date(),
  isAdvancedPayment: false,
  expenseItens: [
    {expenseType: 'tipoteste',
      nfnumber: 'nf123456',
      date: new Date(),
      value: '1345.43'
    },
    {expenseType: 'tipoteste2', nfnumber: 'nf123453'},
    {expenseType: 'tipoteste3', nfnumber: 'nf123454'}
    ]
});
```

So at my form everything is okay, the header fields (desiredPaymentDate and isAdvancedPayment) but I'm trying to bind my itens in a table like this:

```
    oExpenseItensTable.bindItems('newExpense>/expenseItens',
        new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells: [
                new sap.m.Input({
                    value: '{expenseItens>/expenseType}',
                    type: 'Text'
                }),
                new sap.m.Input({
                    value: '{>/nfnumber}',
                    type: 'Text'
                }),
                new sap.m.Input({
                    value: '{/expenseItens>/date}',
                    type: 'Text'
                }),
                new sap.m.Input({
                    value: '{/expenseItens/value}',
                    type: 'Text'
                }),
                new sap.m.Button({
                    icon: 'sap-icon://delete',
                    tooltip: 'Remover item de despesa',
                    press: oController.removeExpenseItem
                })
            ]
        })
    );
```

And I'm almost there... I'm trying every type of field binding... I've tried {nfnumber}, {/nfnumber}, {>/nfnumber}, {expenseItens>/nfnumber}, {/expenseItens>nfnumber}, {Nfnumber}. But nothing works...

PS: As I've three objects at expenseItens collection, there's three empty rows on the table, but all the values are empty. So I think that the binding is working for recognizing the array but it's not working to the property bind of the object.

Anyone knows how is the correct mode?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `{newExpense>nfNumber}`, without the preceding slash.
Because the bound table items are in `expenseItems`, the child properties should be bound *relative* to this node, i.e. without the slash.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code should be like this
    oExpenseItensTable.bindItems('newExpense>/expenseItens',

```
    new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells: [
            new sap.m.Input({
                value: '{newExpense>expenseType}',
                type: 'Text'
            }),
            new sap.m.Input({
                value: '{newExpense>nfnumber}',
                type: 'Text'
            }),
            new sap.m.Input({
                value: '{newExpense>date}',
                type: 'Text'
            }),
            new sap.m.Input({
                value: '{newExpense>value}',
                type: 'Text'
            }),
            new sap.m.Button({
                icon: 'sap-icon://delete',
                tooltip: 'Remover item de despesa',
                press: oController.removeExpenseItem
            })
        ]
    })
);
```